# How can I send a POST request with spaces?

Tags: java, php, android, post

I'm trying to send input from an edittext to PHP. If I send in something with no spaces it works ok, but crashes with spaces and says this:

> illegal character

...which refers to the space.

Obviously it's a matter of getting the quotes correct but for some reason I just can't get this right.

Where do I add the quotes?

Is it in Java during creating the URL?

```
http://example.com/android/project_group_notes_details.php?course=\'"+sessionCourse+"\'";
```

or while creating the Variable?

```
String sessionCouse = "\'Software Development With Spaces\'";
```

or is it somehow done server side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A standard browser takes any spaces entered into the address bar and replaces them with `%20`; HTML's `space` character.

HTTP does not do this, the browser does, meaning that you have two options:

1. Create a function to take in a string and replace all spaces with `%20`;
2. Manually replace spaces with `%20`

For example:

```
String sessionCouse = "\'Software Development With Spaces\'";
```

should actually be

```
String sessionCouse = "\'Software%20Development%20With%20Spaces\'";
```

Comment: And if i want to transform %20 into spaces again, should i use regexp?

Answer (score 0):

When communicating with a backend server programmatically you should use URL encode to encode you input properly:

```
String fullURL = "http://example.com/android/project_group_notes_details.php?course=\'"+ URLEncoder.encode(sessionCouse, "UTF-8") + "\'";
```

Comment: Seems to produce " course='Software+Systems+Development' " Which returns no results even though there is a "Software Systems Development" result in the database.

Comment: The purpose of the URLEncoder is to do just that, encode strings to valid URL:s. Have a look here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters