# how to query mysql containing special character (è, d', è) in php?

Tags: sql, special-characters

I have a file containing French words, and I encoded the file as "Latin-1" (uft-8 didn't work), loaded the file to a table in MySQL. I need to $_POST input ("name") from a web page and use the "name" to query from MySQL. My code is as follows:

```
$name = "d' évaluation perfomance académique";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM application WHERE `Description` = '".$name."'";
```

For normal "name", it can work. But can't work if the "name" containing (è, d', è).

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Please try `URLEncoder.encode("é", "UTF-8")` and tell me what it produces.

Comment: The php iconv() function will translate one character set to another.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Sending POST with Spaces to PHP Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29097627/android-sending-post-with-spaces-to-php-server). (duplicate as it details *how* PHP handles the characters to the database, it needs to pre-process the characters first).

Comment: Doesn't look like the same Q to me.

Comment: By using urlenocde("é", "UTF-8"), "é" is coded as "%C3%A9" ...?@cybermonkey

Comment: Are you aware of SQL injection attacks?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your PHP file is in UTF-8, I believe the following will work:

```
$name = "d' évaluation perfomance académique";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM application WHERE `Description` = '".$name."'";
$sql_latin1 = iconv("UTF-8","ISO-8859-1",$sql);
```

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions.

Comment: This solution was not included in that so called duplicate.

Comment: My answer answers this question. While your answer *does* answer this question, it's frowned upon to answer duplicate questions. Both questions deal with character encoding, and both answers are correct.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But it still can't work.                                 $name = "d' évaluation perfomance académique"; $name_code = iconv("UTF-8","ISO-8859-1",$name); $sql = "SELECT * FROM application WHERE `Description` = '".$name."'"; Still can't get the right result.